# Scrollview not working when i put webview inside scrollView

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

When i put web view inside scroll view then scrollview is not scrolling when touching on web view. it only scrolls when i try to scroll outside web view click.

[image]

```
<ScrollView ref={scrollRef} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
            <View style={styles.htmlContainer(colors)}>
              <View
                onLayout={(e) => {
                  onLayout && onLayout(e);
                }}
                style={[commonStyles.singlePaddingStyle("bottom", 15)]}
              >
                <WebView style={{width:'100%',height:300}} source={{html:html}}/>
              </View>
            </View>
```